# Changing log format in gitlab's "Repository graph"

Tags: git, gitlab

In the default "Repository graph" display in the web UI for gitlab, the messages displayed appear to be generated by "format:%s".  I would like to display information from trailers and have the web output look like "format:[%(trailers:key=foo)%-C()] %s".  I don't mind hard-coding the key "foo, but ideally the key could be selected as a drop down by the user.  How can I configure gitlab to change the log format used for the graph display of commits to include information from trailers?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot which view that is?

Comment: @KamilCuk https://gist.github.com/wrp/cc228abe478047e3e82b2d12f3fb2f00

Comment: I'm looking for a reasonable way to convince people to stop embedding metadata about commits in the subject line of the git message and put it in trailers instead, but to do so I need a simple mechanism to display that data, and gitlab seems a good choice (especially since that is the ui used by the people I'm trying to convince!)